# What are the dimensions of an A4 page, in regards to a Microsoft Access report?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a Microsoft Access report that is exactly the size of one A4 page.

According to [papersizes.org](http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes.htm), the exact dimensions of an A4 page are `29.7cm x 21cm`.

So I have created a new MS Access report using the `Report Design` button. I have turned off headers and footers and set my `Height` property to `29.7cm` and my `Width` property to `21cm`. `Auto Resize` is set to **No**, `Fit to Page` is set to **Yes**.

Whenever I print preview my report, is spans four A4 pages.

So that is what I have tried, and my question is in Microsoft Access, what dimensions do I need to use to create a report that is the same size as a single A4 page?

Comment: What are your page margins set at?  You will need to take those into account as well.  You should be able to set them to 0.  However, most printers will not print to the edges, and will result in clipping on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the height and width property of the report won't work.  You have to set the paper size in the page setup screen, which also allows you to set the margins.